# Which data structure should i use to represent a large amount of records each presents range of items?

Tags: database, data-structures, b-tree, records, avl-tree

I'm looking for **software** represenation for a very large amount of records ( more than 400K records)

Each record has two keys . one for lower bound and one for upper bound. These number represent a range. Also each record has some piece of information lets call it I . In other words , each record aggregates common item indexs , and has some common description about them.

My software is given an item number , and I have to retrive that info about it.

I thought about AVL , B- Tress or fibonaci . But i'm sure which will be the best for that large amount of record . I would deffinately go for AVL / balanced AVL for a small database.

Comment: nope , the range are disticnt , forget to say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a data structure point of view, you search for an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

The wikipedia article is quite good. What you can do, is to augment a (balanced) binary search tree like AVL or Red-Black-Trees like. Interval trees based on binary search tree have an own section in the classical DS book by [Cormen et al.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

A good data structure scales well to large amounts of data. The complexity for the major directory operations are O(k + log n) where n is the number of intervals in the tree and k is the number of overlapping intervals in the range. This is usually pretty good. It grows slowly with the number of of interval items, except for cases where a lot or most intervals overlap all others.

If you cannot hold your data in main memory, a B-Tree would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Any database will do what you want just fine.

If you are searching on an index, the increase in look-up speed when going from 2 to 4 records is the same as going from 2 million to 4 million records...one more level to the tree...it's an exponential relationship.